# I want to start new activity after dragging and dropping a view into another view..how do i do it in the switch case?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have been searching and searching for over a week and I'm not able to figure out how to start a new activity from within a case.

This is a sample drag and drop example code from android studio. How do i add to this?...i want to make a scenario where if i drag a view into another view, a new activity page starts. This is my first ever question on the internet ever.

I feel like giving up and am getting depressed because i have a beginner job offer that i cannot accept unless i do this.

```
public class DragActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drag);
    findViewById(R.id.myimage1).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.myimage2).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.myimage3).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.myimage4).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.topleft).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    findViewById(R.id.topright).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    findViewById(R.id.bottomleft).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    findViewById(R.id.bottomright).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

}

private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
    Drawable enterShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_droptarget);
    Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                // do nothing
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(enterShape);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                owner.removeView(view);
                LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
                container.addView(view);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);

            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: You never execute something like `startActivity(new Intent(Current.this, NewOne.class);` ... What is your problem: Do you have an error or you don't know how to start an activity? Explain with more details. If you have errors so post them

Comment: Hey Robert. ..thanks for taking the time to comment....I know how to start a new activity...I don't know how to start one in a switch case...what I mean is, after "drag_ended" or doing a "drop" of one view into another, I want to start new activity but using normal Intent code isn't working for me.

Comment: I changed my code. Check the comments and try again. Good luck.!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a two image view (Red and Gray) and when drap the red one and drop into the gray a new Activity raised.

#### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnDragListener,
                                                               View.OnTouchListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView left = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.left);
        ImageView right = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.right);

        left.setOnTouchListener(this);
        left.setOnDragListener(this);
        right.setOnDragListener(this); // Added a drag listener to the other view

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case ACTION_DROP: {
                /**
                 * If the item view is the origin return false, reject the drop event
                 */
                if (v.getId() == R.id.left)
                    return false;
                /**
                 * Else accept the event and raise the activity
                 */
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, DragDropActivity.class));
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.right) return false;

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //setup drag
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
            v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="forkandjoin.draganddrop.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="#929292"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### App

[image]

When you drop the red item into the gray item a new Activity is raised.

Enjoy it.

Comment: Hey Robert. ..thanks for taking the time to post...you have solved half my problem...but it starts a new activity no matter where I drop it. If you could  tell me how to reset the left Imageview back to origin when it drops outside the right Imageview I would really appreciate it...thanks again for the answer

Comment: Ok, I will take a minute at night and I let you know. I am working right now but you can check if the drop event is entered on the second view. So you can implements the drag events for the other view. You can tried if you want. Or let me try and I let you know.

Comment: Robert!....you are my savior....thanks a lot...it works now...I will edit what I did...